# Visual Studio 2013. Viewing a PDF file

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am writing a Windows Forms application in which I need to view PDF files via the Web Browser control. When the control is given the Navigate("C:\filepath") command, Windows takes over and asks which program I want to open the file with. All was fine with VS 2010 and XP. I have un-installed "PDF Complete", which was the default PDF viewer, but I now get asked for an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Mike Saunders

Comment: [PDf Viewer Using Dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe) just refer this link.it is about pdf view without acrobat reader or any other controls installed.

Comment: I think the problem is that the webbrowser control (which is IE) has no idea how to render pdf files. I just tried and it opened with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Thanks Mathemats. Visual Studio 2010 handled it fine with XP. I guess my Windows 8.1 is trying to be too clever!

Comment: I have downloaded Adobe Reader and made it the default pdf viewer. The Web Browser control now hosts Adobe Reader with the appropriate file loaded. That works fine. Thanks for your help!